# Remove item from datalist dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am try to remove an option from a datalist dynamically but I cannot seem to get anything to work.

I have tried using .remove but instead of removing a specific option it removes the entire datalist.

Here is the code,

```
var cList = document.querySelector("#Options");
    cList.remove(0);
```

This is the datalist,

```
<datalist id="Options">
        <option id="O1" value="tut">Test</option>
        <option id="O2" value="tut2">Test2</option>
</datalist>
```

This is the result of the code running,

```
<form id="form1"> </form>
```

If you remove the cList.remove(0), you get this,

```
<form id="form1">
<datalist id="Options">
    <option id="O1" value="tut">Test</option>
    <option id="O2" value="tut2">Test2</option>
</datalist>
</form>
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using ***[remove](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp)*** incorrectly. Simply remove the right option, like:

```
cList.children[0].remove()
```

#### Note:

- The *`remove`* method is used to remove the current element it's being run on, hence your element gets deleted.
- What we've done above is to run *`remove()`* on the second child by
  accessing **`cList`**'s child nodes and deleting the one at index ***`0`***.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove an option directly if you have the id for it.  However, you cannot have a purely numeric id.  Rename your option id to something like "option1" and you can use the following.

```
var cList = document.querySelector("#option1");
cList.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a simple jQuery syntax like this:

```js
$("#Options option").eq(0).remove();

/* Or
$("#Options option:first-child").remove();
$("#Options option:nth-child(1)").remove();
$("#Options option").remove('#O1');
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<datalist id = "Options">
    <option id = "O1" value = "tut"> Test </option>
    <option id = "O2" value = "tut2"> Test2 </option>
</datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: I have not learned jQuery yet, I will get into researching it soon though, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

[document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is not a jQuery method, so neither is `remove()`. With jQuery you can simply [empty it](https://api.jquery.com/empty/#empty):

```js
console.log("Before: ", $("#form1").html());
$("#Options").empty();
console.log("After: ", $("#form1").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <datalist id="Options">
      <option id="O1" value="tut">Test</option>
      <option id="O2" value="tut2">Test2</option>
  </datalist>
</form>
```