# How do I initialize the datalist options list before creating the list in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to clear the options for a datalist before adding the options because it has options leftover from the prior call to the function which loads the options. I tried a removeOptions() and that seemed to not display any options at all. Here is my code which populates the datalist options from a spreadsheet.

```
function loadMeasures(selectObject) {
      var food = selectObject.value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
       
        var measureSelect = document.getElementById("measureList");
        measureSelect.removeOptions(); // my attempt at clearing list
        
        ar.forEach(function(item) {
          let option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = item[0];
          measureSelect.appendChild(option);
        });

      }).getTypeList(food)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Probably answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571602/how-do-i-remove-options-from-a-dropdownlist-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, just a guess:

```
var options = document.getElementById("measureList").options;
options.forEach((_,i) => options[i] = null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix suggestion. I must be doing something wrong somewhere else. The change did not not fix this problem but I learned something about the => notation and the _ reference.

Comment: I was able to get a solution using the information from this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755661/remove-item-from-datalist-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve the problem using information from a couple of stackoverflow queries. Here is the code used for the resolution.

called the function below prior to loading the datalist.

```
removeOptions(document.getElementById('measureList'));


function removeOptions(selectElement) {
   var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
   for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
      selectElement.children[i].remove();
   }
  }
```